# How to downgrade DAML SDK version?

Tags: daml

I tried to upgrade DAML SDK for purpose of testing, but now I want to downgrade version for running code already written for 0.13.36 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAML SDK version is controlled project by project by setting the `sdk-version` in `daml.yaml`. So if you have a project written with SDK 0.13.36, just make sure the `daml.yaml` still contains `sdk-version: 0.13.36`. `daml start` and `daml build` will then do their job using that SDK version.